# Удаление поля таблицы с составным первичным ключом laravel многие-ко-многим

Tags: ajax, база-данных, laravel, vue.js, многие-ко-многим

По задаче мне нужно удалить в какой-то момент связь из промежуточной таблицы многие-ко-многим. В ней есть составной первичный ключ из двух столбцов.

Однако выходит такая ошибка:

> message: "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."

> status: 405

Не понимаю, как с этим бороться, потому что, вроде бы, прописал все верно.

Если что, связка Laravel+Vue.

**Код метода отправки:**

```
deleteStation(){
        axios
        .post("/api/v1/keys/", {
            _method: 'DELETE',
            user_id: this.username, 
            station_id: this.station,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.username = "",
            this.station = "",
            this.rule = response.data.data.rule;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response);
          this.errored = true
        }) 
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

**Код в контроллере:**

```
public function destroy(Key $key)
    {
        $key->delete();

        return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST` означает, что у вас ошибка в маршрутах (routes/api.php), либо в их использовании.

К примеру добавив эту строку в routes/api.php:

```
Route::delete('/v1/keys', 'KeyController@destroy')->name('key.destroy');
```

Вы можете удалить ключ послав запрос на URL /api/v1/keys

Больше о маршрутизации:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing